# How to edit the setup exe in Visual [C#]

Tags: visual-studio

How can I edit the setup.exe file so I can make it display where to install, make a desktop icon, ect. It is possible or do I need an external program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might be using a setup project in visual studio.  There is a really good tutorial on the basics of setup projects at http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showtopic58021.htm

Comment: There are lots of other setup options.  WiX is pretty easy to figure out.  http://wix.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Nevermind. I didn't burn it, I used Daemon Tools Lite to mount it.